# Why is Taylor series expansion for $1/(1-x)$ valid only for $x \in (-1, 1)$?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

After finding an expansion of $$ \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots$$
a quick test of various values for $x$ reveals that this expansion is not valid for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}-\{1\}$.

When $x=2$, then $ \frac{1}{1-x} = -1 $.

But $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \ldots > -1$.

What is going on? I checked for divisibility by $0$, but could not find any flaw.

Comment: Try googling "radius of convergence".

Comment: http://archive.org/details/divergentseries033523mbp

Comment: Thanks for the input. What is special about our function that its expansion is not convergent for all reals? Could we deduce certain facts about the properties of the expansion before even attempting to do one?

Comment: The power series representation is valid in the largest disk (in the complex plane) around the origin which doesn't contain a singular point. In this case, $x=1$ is a singularity (because of division by zero), so the power series is not valid outside the unit disk.

Comment: I see @John got to GH Hardy's classic before I did - and you could look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_4_%2B_8_%2B_… . On the whole, though, the usual answers about radius of convergence are much more useful until you encounter contexts in which the Divergent Series material makes sense.

Comment: @DavidToth Physicists have built whole worlds around this. Some of them are really similar to our.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I actually knew about the radius of convergence and that the given series was divergent - I should have asked in a better way that I did not understand why the given series had that property while other functions when expanded have convergent series for all the values. Hardy's book gives me a good direction further.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following is valid for all $x$$$1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
Now taking limit as $n\to\infty $ you see that $x^{n+1}\to 0$ only when $|x|<1$ and that gives your formula.

Comment: Where did you get the right hand side from?

Comment: @scrollout common factorization trick. Try multiplying both sides by the denominator and simplifying.

Answer (score 5):

Well, we have that

$$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Now, we look at $n\to \infty$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k$$

For what $x$ does this limit exist?

Clearly, we're only concerned about $x^{n+1}$. If $|x|>1$, then  $x^{n+1}$ grows large, and there is no limit. If $|x|<1$, then $x-1\neq 0$ and $x^{n+1}$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so in that case, we can assert that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\frac 1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$$

If $x=1$, $x-1=0$ and we find ourselves in trouble. However, we can say that  $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{1^k}}  = n$$ in which case the sequence of partial sums has no limits. Finally, for $x=-1$, we have $(-1)^{n+1}$ which oscillates and has no limit.

Thus, $$\frac{1}{{1 - x}} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{x^k}} $$ makes sense only for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Being quite new to the topic, I'm not 100% sure about this (hope my saying so doesn't violate the etiquette for replies, just trying to be transparent), but the more general Taylor Series I got was the following.

Starting with the definition for the Taylor Series:

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n
$$

We evaluate $f^{(n)}(a)$:
$$ f^{(0)}(a) = (1-a)^{-1} $$
$$ f^{(1)}(a) = (1-a)^{-2} $$
$$ f^{(2)}(a) = (2)(1-a)^{-3} $$
$$ f^{(3)}(a) = (3)(2)(1-a)^{-4} $$
$$ f^{(4)}(a) = (4)(3)(2)(1-a)^{-5} $$
$$ f^{(n)}(a) = n!(1-a)^{-(n+1)} $$

Putting this back into our formula for our Taylor Series:

$$ 
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = 
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n $$
$$ = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!(1-a)^{-(n+1)}}{n!}(x-a)^n $$
$$ = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (1-a)^{-(n+1)}(x-a)^n $$
$$ = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x-a)^n}{(1-a)^n(1-a)} $$
$$ = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \Big(\frac{x-a}{1-a}\Big)^n \frac1{1-a} $$
$$ = \frac1{1-a} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \Big(\frac{x-a}{1-a}\Big)^n $$
$$ f(x) = f(a) \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \Big(\frac{x-a}{1-a}\Big)^n $$

The above line is our final equation for the Taylor Series of $f(x)$. If we evaluate it at $a = 0$ (i.e. we take the MacLaurin Series of $f$), then we get:

$$ f(x) = f(0) 
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 
\Big(\frac{x-0}{1-0}\Big)^n = 
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$

Which is indeed the expansion you had. The reason I bother with the foregoing is to say that this more general Taylor Series $\Bigg( 
f(x) = f(a) \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \big(\frac{x-a}{1-a}\big)^n \Bigg)$ will also have a radius of convergence of 1, just as with your expansion (which I think would be more rightly referred to as a generic Power Series or MacLaurin Series), but the key difference is that this general form of the Taylor Series allows for the interval of convergence to be $(a-1, a+1)$, as opposed to simply $(-1,1)$.

(I apologize in advance if all of this was already obvious or implied in your answer -- I realize it still doesn't really answer the matter of *why* the radius of convergence is 1).