# Why does $ \frac{1}{1 - z} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + \ldots$ when $|z| < 1$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> For $|z| < 1$, $$\frac{1}{1 - z} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + \ldots$$

The fact stated above has appeared in many proofs in my complex analysis textbook, but I have no idea why it is true. Can someone elaborate?

Someone suggested I expand $ (1 - z)^{-1} $, which I tried before posting this question. Perhaps I am wrong, but if $ f(z) = (1- z)^{-1} $ then $ f^{(n)}(z) = n(1 - z)^{-(n + 1)} $ which gives me a Taylor expansion of $ \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(1 - z)^{-(n + 1)}}{(n - 1)!} $

I don't see how this helps :(

Comment: Hint - Expand $(1-z)^{-1}$

Comment: See the answers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201289/why-is-taylor-series-expansion-for-1-1-x-valid-only-for-x-in-1-1/201292#201292. The same argument works for the complex case also.

Comment: I think you should check your expression for the derivative. $$f'(z) = (1-z)^{-2},\quad f''(z) = 2(1-x)^{-3},\quad f'''(z) = 3.2(1-z)^{-4},\quad \dots$$

Comment: Your Taylor series computation is incorrect (and the $n$ in your derivative computation should be $n!$). Remember a Taylor series is always a sum of the form $\sum a_n z^n$, where the coefficient $a_n$ of $z^n$ is obtained by *evaluating* the $n$th derivative of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show by simple algebra that
$$
(1-z)(1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^N) = 1-z^{N+1},
$$
or equivalently
$$
1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^N = \frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}.
$$
If $|z|<1$ then $z^{N+1}$ converges to zero as $N$ tends to infinity and you are left with
$$
1+z+z^2+\ldots=\frac{1}{1-z}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the formula for n-th sum of geometric progression

$ S_n = 1 + q + ... + q^n $

$ qS_n =q + q^2 + ... + q^{n+1}$

$ (1-q)S_n = 1 - q^{n+1}$

$ S_n = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$

If |q| < 1, then $ |q|^{n+1} \rightarrow 0 $ and then $q^{n+1} \rightarrow 0$ and $S_n \rightarrow \frac{1}{1-q}$

Comment: You may also show that if $|q| = 1$ this formula doesn't work. Take for example q = 1 and q = -1 and check that in these cases finite limit doesn't exist.

The same thing if |q| > 1: in this case $|q|^n \rightarrow \infty$ and so again we don't have any finite limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cool calculation that doesn't assume you already know the sum or remember how to sum a geometric series:

First, prove the sum converges (by any sort of comparison test). Denote it by $S(z)$. Then:

$$S(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + \ldots = 1 + z(1 + z + z^2 + \ldots) = 1 + zS(z)$$

giving the required result.

Comment: Is that not *how* to sum a geometric series?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Taylor series. The radius of convergence is a standard calculus exercise.

It is also the geometric series formula. The same proof that works in the finite sum case also works for the infinite sum, when it converges.